# I'm editing an .htaccess file with regex redirects, how to add "-" to \w pattern?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following redirect in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/(\w+)/?$ /projects.php?task=$1
```

If I'm trying to access a URL like /tasks/nov-1 it will say object not found as \w does not accept "-". Can you please help with adding "-" in the above redirect rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this rule to accept hyphen and also it is recommended to use correct flags in this rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^tasks/([\w-]+)/?$ projects.php?task=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Flags are:

- `L` is for Last rule
- `QSA` is for query string append
- `NC` is for ignore case

Please note that `L` flag marks the last rule for current iteration of `mod_rewrite` loop. It behaves like `continue` in a `while` loop not like a `break` so it doesn't end the loop immediately. The rewriting process will be started again if the request has been rewritten. So other rules may get applied after the rule with the `L` flag.

On Apache `2.4` there is an `END` flag which acts like `break` and  immediately halts the full rewriting process.

Comment: Additionally it should get mentioned that the `L` flag marks the last rule _for this run_ , not in total. The rewriting process will be started again if the request has been rewritten. So other rules _may_ get applied after the rule with the `L` flag. There is an `END` flag which actually immediately halts the full rewriting process.

Comment: Good points @arkascha, have added it in answer.